How to convert to List<String> to Map<String,String> in Dart?
I have List<String> = ["name","class","age"];
I want this list to be converted to Map<String,String>;
Like Map<String,String>["name":"name","class":"class","age":"age"];
How to achieve that?

the list does not contain the keys so you must specify how you are getting the keys, it will then be a simple iteration to assign values

This is an odd data structure.  Perhaps you want a Set instead?

I had this before. Here is how I do it.
List<String> list = ["name", "class", "age"];

// Convert the list to a map
Map<String, String> map = Map.fromIterable(
  list,
  key: (item) => item,
  value: (item) => item,
);

// Print the map (You can use this map in your Flutter app)
print(map);


Output: {name: name, class: class, age: age}
Happy flutter !

I recommend not using Map.fromIterable, in general. It's not safely typed.
I'd use the solution by @julemand101 instead. Using literals is better than almost all the fromSomething methods of Map, so forget they existed.

One way to do it would be:
void main() {
  List<String> list = ["name", "class", "age"];

  Map<String, String> map = {
    for (final entry in list) entry: entry,
  };

  print(map); // {name: name, class: class, age: age}
}

